# No consigo compilar despues de actualizar Visual Sutdio a 16.9

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

**texto en negrita**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]mi proyecto  xamarin forms pero xamarin.android no me quiere compilar ni reecompilar, se queda como la imagen que anexe no sigue el proceso de compilacion, todos los sdk estan actualizados, alguna sugerencia ? ya repare vs y desinstale y volvi a instalar y como quiera sigue el problema, elimine las carpeteas bin y obj de cada proyecto y nada...

Comment: Es muy raro que no compile sin darte un error. Podrias cambiar de proyecto de inicio, y volver a colocar android para ver si lanza algun error.

Comment: ya lo he hecho, y sigue teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: Mi recomendación, cuando no sabes qué hacer porque Visual Studio deja de compilar un proyecto (lamentablemente ocurre con mucha frecuencia), o deja de reconocerte cosas como el espacio `System` (xD) es que borres la carpeta .vs que está oculta en el directorio donde tengas el fichero de la solución .sln

Comment: lo intente y como quiera sigue igual